# Batch file always stops

Tags: batch-file, crash, directory

EDIT: FIXED it turns out the problem was not including quotes around '"ICO=%%~nxF"'

So I have almost perfected my automated folder icon changer, but now it works well but with one slight problem, it will run and the stop always at the 113th folder. I have no idea why it stops at that number and in another folder it runs until around the 160th folder. Why does my batch file crash?

```
@ECHO OFF

set ICOINI=Desktop.ini


for /D %%d IN (*) do (  
    set "myDIR=%%~d"
    call :write_File myDIR
)

Pause

goto End_File

:Write_File

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FOLDER=!%~1!"

attrib +a +s "!FOLDER!" /d /s

for %%F in ("!FOLDER!\Icon\*.ico") do (set ICO=%%~nxF)

IF EXIST "!FOLDER!\%ICOINI%" attrib -a -s -h "!FOLDER!\%ICOINI%"

(
    echo [.ShellClassInfo]
    echo IconResource=!CD:~2!\!FOLDER!\Icon\%ICO%, 0
    echo IconFile=!CD:~2!\!Folder!\Icon\%ICO%
    echo IconIndex=0
    echo InfoTip=%ICO:~0,-4%
    echo.
    echo FolderType=Videos
    echo DefaultDropEffect=4
    echo ConfirmFileOp=0
)>"!FOLDER!\%ICOINI%"

attrib -a +s +h "!FOLDER!\%ICOINI%"

echo !FOLDER!

endlocal

goto :EOF

:End_File

exit /b
```

I would love to tell you where or who it exits but it just closes around 1/2 - 2/3 through running.

Comment: Remove the line `@echo off`, open a cmd.exe windows, run the batch file from that window, and it will show you where it stops.  Also are there any error messages?

Comment: @David Ruhmann No, there are no error messages at all. Although I cannot seem to run it in cmd.exe as it will only run from my documents. I cannot seem to change the directory.

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ICOINI=Desktop.ini"

for /D %%d IN (*) do (
     set "myDIR=%%~d"
     call :write_File "!myDIR!"
)
goto:eof
```

Comment: The changes to the script results in problems with any folder name that contains special characters.

Comment: The only important change is `call :write_File "!myDIR!"`

Comment: Tried changing the position of delayedexpansion and !myDIR! but this just causes it to skip everything and finishes at the Pause without doing anything, I don't understand why that is.